# Fastest way to retrieve list of files by search criteria - c#

Tags: c#

I have a directory structure with txt files.

I want to get a list of file names where the modified/creation date is between a range.

So far, I have this:

```
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MotionWise\Manifest\000EC902F17F");
        DateTime from_date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-300);
        DateTime to_date = DateTime.Now;
        List<FileInfo> files = directory.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= from_date && file.LastWriteTime <= to_date).ToList();
```

Now,I am only interested in the full path name.

If I enumerate through the files list I can add the full path name to a new list/array etc.  but this seems a waste of extra effort as I feel there is a way to do this in the lambada code?

If it can be done in the lambada code will not the selection by file info be too 'heavy'? Is there a way to just select full path name without 'loading' each entry into a file info?

I have been toying with the idea of executing the dir DOS command and capturing the output in the Process class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only interested in the paths don't use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` because it returns an array and because it is a `FileInfo[]` where each `FileInfo` object includes all informations that you're not interested in anyway. You can use `File.GetLastWriteTime` to get it.

Instead use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` which lazily returns only paths that are matching your filter criteria and the search pattern.

```
List<string> paths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\MotionWise\Manifest\000EC902F17F", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(path => {
        DateTime lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
        return lastWriteTime >= from_date && lastWriteTime <= to_date;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Tim, Any reason for making this wiki?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: No, accident.

Answer (score 4):

Just `Select` on the `FullName`:

```
List<string> files = directory.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                              .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= from_date && file.LastWriteTime <= to_date)
                              .Select(f => f.FullName)
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: You made it look so easy! Thank you. I will click it as the accepted answer in 8 minutes (as it will not let me before then)

Comment: oops another has popped up

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You're absolutely correct. I've fixed the typo, thanks!

Comment: @AndrewSimpson And that is why we make you wait 10 min.

Comment: a wise mechanism that I see the owrth of now

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Glad it worked out for you! Good luck!

Comment: thanks, your code was an improvement on mine so i gave yuo a thumbs up. Thanks for youur input much appreciated

Comment: Also note this can screw you sometime.. You need `fileInfo.Refresh()` to get reliable results..